# When tabulate numbers from a list Mathematica changes them?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to tabulate a list of numbers but Mathematica slightly changes these numbers?!

Here is the list

```
Hdrz = {-1.19293392628635630 + 
0.333274064763606160 I, -0.89380004035801760 - 
0.36959523498813230 I, -0.77633233787938280 - 
0.08159597927539744 I, -0.75080684622772420 - 
0.62498786768731270 I, -0.68142831803002260 + 
0.72467158753569390 I, -0.67023673404361500 + 
0.23777408481240340 I, -0.49219298410279894 - 
0.87189348958859570 I, -0.43301960306453147 + 
1.16666923455551100 I, -0.09073698351093003 + 
5.81549234664283400 I, -0.05400852949041188 + 
0.89514817303035410 I, 
0.02586935813180266 - 1.00949126186999520 I, 
0.12708577172546760 - 1.15163844397230460 I, 
0.34121878330887984 + 1.15526153099421380 I, 
0.54897412279415590 + 0.52784091826586540 I, 
0.56339918267451470 - 0.21257825928341670 I, 
0.61400656995488830 - 0.77163398642220390 I, 
0.74873548937020160 + 0.81131323943560500 I, 
0.89105134103005410 + 0.21903754849588017 I, 
0.99621116079027920 - 0.29716265051942590 I, 
1.17894452321354700 - 0.49590555492518335 I};

Grid[Table[{NumberForm[Hdrz[[i]], {18, 18}]}, {i, 20}], Frame -> All]
```

some of the wrong numbers are highlighted

[image]

Comment: By default, *Mathematica* uses 16 decimals of precision. What you're seeing is merely rounding of the numbers. If you need these extra digits, you can do `0.49590555492518335\`18` or similar

Comment: Is possible to apply this directly to the whole list? or I should do it for each element by hand?

Comment: I believe you can use `SetPrecision`.

Comment: I tried it with `SetAccuracy` but the same problem is maintained

Comment: Your problem exemplifies that it's a bad idea to transport real numbers from one application to another by printing them in decimal form and then re-parsing them on the other side. Much better to use a format that stays in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), for example [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format), or even a simple binary dump of the numbers to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers here [SetPrecision and setting precision with a backtick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174130/setprecision-and-setting-precision-with-a-backtick) `SetPrecision[]` and single back-tick are not the same, nor are `SetAccuracy[]` and double back-ticks after a number.

Similarly, you can't use `Rationalize` or most other functions I've tried because the numbers are interpreted as machine precision unless they have back-ticks after them or are obviously exact numbers.

It may not be the most elegant, but I think you can get around this by interpreting them as strings, removing the decimal place, dividing them back down to their actual values in exact arithmetic, and then setting the accuracy or precision there. The exact details may vary depending on whether all of your numbers look like the ones provided above.

```
hdrzString = "-1.19293392628635630+0.333274064763606160 \
I,-0.89380004035801760-0.36959523498813230 \
I,-0.77633233787938280-0.08159597927539744 \
I,-0.75080684622772420-0.62498786768731270 \
I,-0.68142831803002260+0.72467158753569390 \
I,-0.67023673404361500+0.23777408481240340 \
I,-0.49219298410279894-0.87189348958859570 \
I,-0.43301960306453147+1.16666923455551100 \
I,-0.09073698351093003+5.81549234664283400 \
I,-0.05400852949041188+0.89514817303035410 \
I,0.02586935813180266-1.00949126186999520 \
I,0.12708577172546760-1.15163844397230460 \
I,0.34121878330887984+1.15526153099421380 \
I,0.54897412279415590+0.52784091826586540 \
I,0.56339918267451470-0.21257825928341670 \
I,0.61400656995488830-0.77163398642220390 \
I,0.74873548937020160+0.81131323943560500 \
I,0.89105134103005410+0.21903754849588017 \
I,0.99621116079027920-0.29716265051942590 \
I,1.17894452321354700-0.49590555492518335 I"

hdrzExact = 
  SetAccuracy[
    ToExpression[StringSplit[StringReplace[hdrzString, "." -> ""], ","]]/
      10^17, 20]
Column[hdrzExact, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Table of numbers with added precision/accuracy.]

Of course, if you'd prefer, you can change the accuracy to any value you like or you can remove `SetAccuracy[..., 20]` and work with them as exact numbers.